# What is difference between contiguous subarray and subarray?

Tags: arrays, sub-array

Given an array `A = [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]`

Sub arrays of array `A = [[-2], [1], [-3]...[-2,1],[1,-3]...[-2,1,-3]...]`

Contiguous subarrays will as well have same list `[[-2], [1], [-3]...[-2,1],[1,-3]...[-2,1,-3]...]`
Then what is the difference between a sub-array and a contiguous sub-array?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I don't think these are formally defined terms. Where are you reading this from?

Comment: In c language. I had question which says return max sum of all contiguous sub arrays given an array of length L

Comment: @MrudulaNudurupati C does not have "sub-arrays". If you're taking a course in C then you need to speak to your lecturer/prof for clarification. Additionally, in C all arrays are always contiguous (otherwise pointer arithmetic wouldn't work) - so it sounds like you're misunderstanding the source-material.